# qemu uses uefi to install the guest of redhad6.0, use the vnc connect it which is stuck

Tags: redhat, qemu

I want to use uefi(udk2-->ovmf.fd) to install redhad6.0, but after I enter uefi and start up, I cannot use vnc to connect to it,The screen is black or often stuck, nor can I use the console of other pages, or it is a special slow to be able to use it. It's sure that the virtual machine is not crash. Anad the same operation is normal for redhad6.1 systems.

1.compile udk2 generate ovmf.fd
compile config:
make -C BaseTools/Source/C
./OvmfPkg/build.sh -D DEBUG_ON_SERIAL_PORT=true
2.run qemu with "-bios /bin/OVMF.fd"
3.use vnc to connet it

I hope to use qemu + uefi to install the guest of redhat6.0

qemu command line:
`/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name guest=GUS1b7e4ade-831e-46dd-b0b8-89e1a8e6c476,debug-threads=on -S -object {"qom-type":"secret","id":"masterKey0","format":"raw","file":"/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-28-GUS1b7e4ade-831e-46d/master-key.aes"} -machine pc-i440fx-6.2,accel=kvm,usb=off,dump-guest-core=off -cpu Broadwell-IBRS,vmx=off  **-bios /bin/OVMF.fd**  -m size=8388608k,slots=64,maxmem=536870912k -overcommit mem-lock=off -smp 8,maxcpus=16,sockets=4,dies=1,cores=4,threads=1 -object {"qom-type":"memory-backend-ram","id":"ram-node0","size":2147483648} -numa node,nodeid=0,cpus=0-1,memdev=ram-node0 -object {"qom-type":"memory-backend-ram","id":"ram-node1","size":2147483648} -numa node,nodeid=1,cpus=2-3,memdev=ram-node1 -object {"qom-type":"memory-backend-ram","id":"ram-node2","size":2147483648} -numa node,nodeid=2,cpus=4-5,memdev=ram-node2 -object {"qom-type":"memory-backend-ram","id":"ram-node3","size":2147483648} -numa node,nodeid=3,cpus=6-7,memdev=ram-node3 -uuid 1b7e4ade-831e-46dd-b0b8-89e1a8e6c476 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=85,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=1,id=pci.1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -device nec-usb-xhci,id=usb1,bus=pci.0,addr=0xa -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 -device ahci,id=sata0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 -device ahci,id=sata1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0xb -blockdev {"driver":"http","url":"http://10.30.97.42:28000/0e3e7ca1-aa29-487f-a8a6-f7478d62da2e/data/rhel-server-6.0-x86_64-dvd.iso","node-name":"libvirt-3-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-3-format","read-only":true,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-3-storage"} -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=1,drive=libvirt-3-format,id=ide0-1-1,bootindex=2 -device floppy,unit=0,id=fdc0-0-0 -blockdev {"driver":"iscsi","portal":"10.30.97.42:20559","target":"iqn.2018-11.xxx.com.cn:34e1b917-a491-42bd-a56a-54367dc3dc85id97591919","lun":1,"transport":"tcp","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-1-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-1-storage"} -device ide-hd,bus=sata0.0,drive=libvirt-1-format,id=sata0-0-0,bootindex=1,write-cache=on -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev pty,id=charserial1 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial1,id=serial1 -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,fd=87,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel1,fd=88,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=2,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=org.qemu.client_guest_tool.0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel2,fd=89,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=3,chardev=charchannel2,id=channel2,name=org.qemu.client_guest_tool.1 -chardev socket,id=charchannel3,fd=90,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=4,chardev=charchannel3,id=channel3,name=topsec_clip_board.0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel4,fd=91,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=5,chardev=charchannel4,id=channel4,name=topsec_clip_board.1 -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel5,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=6,chardev=charchannel5,id=channel5,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -chardev spiceport,id=charchannel6,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=7,chardev=charchannel6,id=channel6,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 -chardev pty,id=charconsole1 -device virtconsole,chardev=charconsole1,id=console1 -device usb-tablet,id=input2,bus=usb.0,port=1 -spice port=5908,addr=::0.0.0.0,image-compression=glz,jpeg-wan-compression=always,streaming-video=filter,seamless-migration=on -vnc [::0.0.0.0]:9,password -device VGA,id=video0,vgamem_mb=64,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0xc -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -device pvpanic -msg timestamp=on`